# Are types in Python's typing library global variables?

Tags: python, scope, type-hinting

I am integrating type hinting into a large Python project, and decided it would be a good idea to put all of my types into a single module that other modules could simply `import *` from.

Here's a (greatly) simplified version of `types.py`:

```py
from typing import Union
Value = Union[float, int]
num = 3
```

However, when I try to import `Value` from `types.py`, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'Value' from 'ntupledicts.types'`. If I import `num` from `types.py`, things go just fine. **Are types not global variables?** If they aren't, is the best solution really to copy-paste the type aliases at the top of every file that uses them? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: `types` is the name of a built-in library. Try changing the name

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that wasn't the problem. I can successfully import `num` from `types.py`. I still renamed the file, though — I don't want to mess with Python internals.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, I cannot reproduce this error. These objects work like any other, there's nothing special about them. You should be able to import `Value`.